# Can we wrap any objects or variable with bool type and with list type too in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to wrap variable with bool type and with list type too is it possible to do that in flutter?

Comment: Not clear what ur question is

Comment: Couldn't understand your question. Could you please elaborate your question and include relevant code?

Comment: Sir i am fetching the files using filepicker plugin and i have fetched that file too but now i want to add those fetched files into list type .

Answer (score 0):

If I gues right you can design a custom Data model like bellow

```
class Data{
  bool status;
  List<File> fileList = [];
}
```

and then you can access or manipulate then by creating `object` on `Data` `class`

```
void accessData(){
    Data data = Data();
    data.status = true;
    data.fileList.add('Your file');
  }
```

Comment: if you could specify your scenario perfectly then we can help you better.